# copyWithZone error

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I am using the following code to instantiate the view SenderPlayerViewController and pass the object "session" :

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState: GKPeerConnectionState)state {
switch (state) {
    case GKPeerStateConnected:
        NSLog(@"Connected Central");
        if ([settings.playerType isEqualToString:@"SENDER"]){                 
            SenderPlayerViewController *myViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SenderPlayerViewController"];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
            myViewController.currentSession=session;

        }

        break;            
    case GKPeerStateDisconnected:
        NSLog(@"Disconnected Central");
        self.currentSession = nil;
        break;
}   
}
```

The header file of view SenderPlayerViewController is :

```
@interface CentralViewController : UIViewController {
Settings *settings;}
@property (nonatomic, copy) GKSession *currentSession;

@end
```

When the code is executed i get the following error :

```
[GKSession copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9661200
```

Can you please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) GKSession *currentSession;
```

is wrong. GKSession is not a copiable object. So you should just grab a reference to it by retaining:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) GKSession *currentSession;
```

Comment: I made the change you recommend but i still get the same error

Comment: Well - it is *obvious* from your error message that this is THE problem. Did you do the wrong declaration multiple times? Are you sure you have properly recompiled all your sources?